# Disable iPad horizontal scrolling

Tags: ipad, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website which has elements outside the viewport, which I use for animations, they basically kick in , every time you scroll to a different section of the page.

The problem is you can scroll horizontally thus taking the website's content out of the viewport and having access to the element which shouldn't be seen (something like an element with {right:-660px;} which should be well out of sight till it's supposed to come into the viewport{right:100px} or something).

[image: reference of the problem]

Have already tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
```

And

```
body,html{overflow-x:hidden!important}
```

I'm sure this is a problem which might have many losing sleep over, just like me.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Mac's and on iOS, `overflow-x:hidden` on the body isn't as forgiving as it is on PCs. If you must have an element that has to appear offscreen, put it in a `div` that is not wider than the screen and has `overflow:hidden` on it.

E.g.

```
.overflow-div { max-width: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
.my-animatable-element { position: absolute; right: -660px; }

<body>
 <div class="overflow-div">
    <div class="my-animatable-element"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

A link, or code, would really go a long way in helping you solve your problem.

Note: `max-width:100%` isn't necessary in my simplified example, but it might be in your specific case, which is why I put it in.

Comment: Hello Adam, I've tried that as well, no luck still. My absolutely positioned elements are in a div which are hidden. The viewport extends till their position if you swipe left. I have an over wrapping div#page which does not hide the horizontal overflow of the div with the styles applied.

Comment: Then perhaps you have something else on your page that is too wide and causing the page to scroll horizontally. Do you have a link?

Comment: Yes that was exactly the case Adam, you helped me identify the blind spot. :) I'll mark it as the correct answer, just add your comment above. Cheers and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
 <style type="text/css">
 body {
 overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: have tried that as well, not working. I had mentioned trying that in my description as well but it seems to have been cut out due to the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
This is what worked for me:

```
div {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```